# Why does nodejs wait a long time before exiting

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, polkadot-js

i try to write a Creation Operator to got a observable from a wsprovider on polkadot.js.
and try to got polkadot event.

this is the code

```js
import {from, fromEvent, of,Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {tap,mergeMap} from "rxjs/operators"

import { WsProvider } from '@polkadot/api';

console.time("main")
const urls = of("wss://192")

const fromWs =  (url:string) => {
  const ws = new WsProvider(url,0);
  ws.connect().then(val => console.timeLog("main",val)).catch(console.error)
  return new Observable((subscriber) => {

    ws.on("disconnected",()=>{
      console.timeLog("main","wss disconnected")
      subscriber.next(url);
      subscriber.complete()
    })
    ws.on('error', () =>{
      console.timeLog("main","wss error")
      subscriber.complete()
    })
    ws.on('connected' ,() => {
      console.timeLog("main", `${url} connected`)
    })
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.timeLog("main", `${url} timeout`)
      ws.disconnect().then(val=> console.timeLog("main",'ws disconnect')).catch(err => console.error("disconnect error"))
      subscriber.complete()
    },2000)
  })
}

urls.pipe(
    tap(console.log),
    mergeMap( (url:string) =>{
      return fromWs(url)
    }),
).subscribe({
  next: val => console.timeLog("main", 'subcrnext'),
  error: err=> console.timeLog("main", "sub error"),
  complete: () => console.timeLog("main", "sub complete")
})

process.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.timeLog("main",'System exit');
});
```

and i try to execute it by ts-node.

```bash
➜  rxjsexample ts-node src/main.ts
wss://192
main: 11.959ms undefined
main: 2.013s wss://192 timeout
main: 2.015s wss error
main: 2.016s sub complete
main: 2.017s wss disconnected
main: 2.018s ws disconnect
main: 2:10.176 (m:ss.mmm) System exit
```

at 2.018s, the network conenct is disconnect.
but at 2m10s, the nodejs just exits.

What is nodejs doing during this time?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **a lot**.

`node.js` is an event-loop based runtime which goes through [a set of prefixed phases](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) at each loop.

Once your timer function is executed, there should be no more event providers (timers, I/O...) and the runtime will go through a cleanup phase executing any `close` event handlers along with the *process#exit* event.

Hence between the timer function execution and the internal checking / cleanup, there still statements to execute which will lead to the time laps you are seeing between the last *userland* timer function and the last *userland* `exit` event handler.

Comment: How do I find out which statements are executed at this stage?

Comment: You can jump right into the [node](https://github.com/nodejs/node) source code.

Comment: @kula You can check how the nodejs event loop works here: [event loop](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=JC5vbignYnV0dG9uJywgJ2NsaWNrJywgZnVuY3Rpb24gb25DbGljaygpIHsKICAgIHNldFRpbWVvdXQoZnVuY3Rpb24gdGltZXIoKSB7CiAgICAgICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coJ1lvdSBjbGlja2VkIHRoZSBidXR0b24hJyk7ICAgIAogICAgfSwgMjAwMCk7Cn0pOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkhpISIpOwoKc2V0VGltZW91dChmdW5jdGlvbiB0aW1lb3V0KCkgewogICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coIkNsaWNrIHRoZSBidXR0b24hIik7Cn0sIDUwMDApOwoKY29uc29sZS5sb2coIldlbGNvbWUgdG8gbG91cGUuIik7!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D)